# NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. T

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

tensorflow version 2.3.1
numpy version 1.20

below the code

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

we got

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
> (lstm_2/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate
> that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not
> supported

it seems to me a crazy error!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I solved with numpy downgrade to 1.18.5

```
pip install -U numpy==1.18.5
```

Comment: I was just looking at the 1.20 release notes.  There are a number of low level changes (which I didn't fully understand), so I'm not surprised that there compatibility issues with `tensorflow`.  I don't know who has to fix what.

Comment: no idea waiting for a better support ... also I'm curious why nobody found a similar issue

Comment: I just did as well :)

Comment: Numpy version 1.19.5 resolves the issues as well.

Comment: `numpy 1.18.5` is not compatible with `python 3.9`, so I had to downgrade to `python 3.8` first before installing `numpy 1.18.5`. (`numpy==1.18.5 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']`)

Comment: I had the same issue with "numpy-1.20.3" and downgrading to "numpy-1.18.5" as mentioned in this answer solved the issue.

Comment: What happen when another library requires ```numpy 1.20.0```? It would give an error. This a good solution but you need to be careful when you are using different versions.

Comment: I just had the same error. Downgrading to 1.19 has solved my problem.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using anaconda:

`conda install numpy=1.19`

Answer (score 15):

Similar issue, with

- tensorflow 2.3.0
- numpy 1.20.3

on Windows 7.

Solved by modifying `tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py`, replacing

```py
  def __array__(self):
    raise NotImplementedError(
```

at line #845~846 with

```py
  def __array__(self):
    raise TypeError(
```

.

Comment: This worked for me. I found another solution at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9706#issuecomment-875123676 which also worked.

Comment: Even though downgrading to numpy 1.19 also works, but it breaks some other stuff including spyder.

Comment: @Chris Fu, Thanks; it is working fine with NumPy 1.23.4

Comment: I like the idea to change library itself instead of influencing dependent libraries

Answer (score 5):

Tensorflow 2.5 update:

tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu 2.5 packages still includes numpy-1.19.5 as a dependency.

The error referenced in this post will be reproduced if tensorflow 2.5 installation is mixed with numpy>1.19.5

tensorflow-2.5, numpy-1.19.5 are compatible with python-3.9

Comment: problem is i cant depreciate due to other package dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Same issue with tf 2.4.1, numpy 1.21, and python 3.9  .

Downgrading numpy to 1.19.2 with

```
conda install numpy==1.19.2
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by downgrading python from 3.8 to 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with M1 chip. Here is the how I fixed:

```
conda create create --name tf
conda activate tf
conda install numpy ~=1.18.5
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

and voila you are ready to go !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `tensorflow 2.5.0` and `numpy 1.21.2`. There were suggestions [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/9706#issuecomment-877788105) to make changes in `array_ops.py` file but this didn't work for me. Another answer in the same page with following steps worked.

```py
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

Basically these steps don't downgrade numpy but either upgrades or keeps it at the same level. Above steps upgraded `tensorflow 2.7.0` and `numpy 1.21.4` and my code ran without any issues.