# NotImplementedError in tensorflow 2.4.1 & numpy 1.20.3 & Python 3.8.12 ubuntu conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Adding the input layer and the LSTM layer

```
model.add(LSTM(units = 4, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = (None, 1)))
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (lstm_1/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_19256/3048822115.py in <module>
      1 # adding the input layer and the LSTM layer
----> 2 model.add(LSTM(units = 4, activation = 'sigmoid', input_shape = (None, 1)))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    515     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    516     try:
-

Comment: Please include additional code; `model` may not be referencing a keras model. I would suspect `model` is actually holding a numpy type, try viewing what type it is with `print(type(model))` or something similar

Comment: print(type(model))

<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>

Comment: Put the traceback in your question, not in a unreadable comment.

Comment: Did you try downgrading numpy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66207609/notimplementederror-cannot-convert-a-symbolic-tensor-lstm-2-strided-slice0-t?rq=1

Comment: not yet @Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade your Numpy version to 1.19.2 or 1.19.5 for TF 2.4

Note:Default version of 2.8 is Numpy 1.21.5 .